# How can I detect when all numbers are a certain value?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to write "you win" when all numbers are "green" (in this case, equal to the constant `Fez.color.g`). This is the script I have so far:

```
void Start () {
    for (int SD = 0; SD < 10; SD++) {
        number = Random.Range (0, 9);
        print ("X:" + X);

        Fez.text = number.ToString ();
        //print (Fez);
    } else {
        Fez.text = ("   ");
    }
}

void Update ()
{
    if (number != Fez.color.g) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            print (script.randomnumber);
            if (script.randomnumber == number) {
                Fez.color = new Color (0, 1, 0);
                //Destroy( number);
                //  print (SD);
            } else {
            }
        } else {
            print (" YOu  win");
        }
    }
}
```

But right now there's a bug, it prints "you win" even when all numbers aren't green. How do I change this to print the text only when all the numbers are green?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to accomplish with this. Try clearly stating what you want to accomplish, what your problem is, and any other conditions that might help explain it.

Comment: Also, make sure you properly format your code. Scoped variables should start with a lowercase letter; SD is not a proper name for a for loop member, either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fundamental issue you're having is that you refer to "numbers" but you only seem to track *one* number. To store multiple numbers you want [an array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx):

```
int numbers = new int[10]; // 10 numbers.
```

Then you can assign values to individual elements of the array in your `Start` function:

```
for (int SD = 0; SD < numbers.Length; ++SD) {
    numbers[SD] = Random.Range(0, 9);
}
```

Then you can check to see if they are "all" some value. One simple way to do this is to assume they are all the desired value:

```
bool areAllGreen = true;
```

But then check every number anyway; if you ever see one that isn't the desired value, update the state of `areAllGreen`:

```
for (int SD = 0; SD < numbers.Length; ++SD) {
  if(numbers[SD] != Fez.color.g) {
    areAllGreen = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

You can do the above in your `Update` function. Then you can check `if (areAllGreen) print("You win!");`

Comment: if i want instantiate  numbers for  distance  together (x = 2f) what do i do?

Comment: @pezy I won't "write the script completely" because I don't believe in doing all your work for you. I may be able to help you with your follow-up question but I'm afraid I don't quite follow what you mean. Can you clarify?